# how to run some web scraping script in django webapp

Tags: python, django

i want to create a django webapp for electronic component selection tool.
one of its functionality will be to show all products available.
i have written script to do so. which works well in code editor.
it shows output like this:

```
(1, 'Automation and Control')
(2, 'Accessories')
(3, 'Controllers - Accessories')
.
.
.
```

i have recently started learning django.and i know how to create views, render html
pages etc.

**what i am really struggling with is how to and where to  use my script in the django webapp**
so that when user is directed to home page all the products will be shown

code that i have written:

```
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get("https://www.digikey.in/products/en")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
base_url = "https://www.digikey.in"
mydivs = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "flymenu__item-title"})

name_link = {}

count = 1
for i in mydivs:
    name = i.getText()
    link = i.get('href')
    name_link[name] = link

count = 1
name_num = {}
for i in name_link.keys():
    name = i
    name_num[count] = name
    count += 1
    

for pair in name_num.items():
    print(pair)
```

what i expect is

1. where to put this code in django app so that when user visits
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/ output shown as above will be shown to user

Comment: I suggest you to put it inside an app where you use this script or if you require it in multiple apps then place it in a folder called `scripts` and name the file what you want. I have a django project that scrapes covid19 information and named the script that scrapes the information as `track.py` and placed it inside an app where I use it. The project is live on heroku. https://covid19tracker-ajay.herokuapp.com/

Comment: i tried  to  keep the script in views.py of  one of the app it didnt work, can i have a look at the entire project of yours so that i will understand when the script gets called

Comment: Visit this repo : https://github.com/Ajay2810-hub/Covid19Tracker

Comment: i visited your github profile. thanks for your help ajay

Comment: why r is used here URL = r"https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/?utm_campaign=homeAdvegas1%3F"

Comment: It's the URL from where I scrape the data.

Comment: prefixing string literal with r creates raw string ,This treats characters such as backslash ('\') as a literal character. This also means that this character will not be treated as a escape character.